# How to run Selenium webDriver test cases in chrome using maven

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new new to Maven.Please let me know how to run selenium test cases in chrome using Maven . Thanks in advance.

Comment: let me know what YOU have tried?

Comment: I tried to add dependency .After that only i realised it not correct way but i am still in confusion .

Comment: Here is a maven template that will help you get started: https://github.com/Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template

Answer (score -1):

Here is a step-by-step guide with an example of Selenium + TestNG + Maven.

http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/creating-and-running-a-simple-selenium-webdriver-test/2011-09-15

Comment: Although your answer may help the user, answers containing just a link does not constitute a good answer on StackOverflow.  See [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @sircapsalot quote: _...Make sure your answer provides that – **or a viable alternative** . The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker **going in the right direction is helpful** , but do try to **mention** any limitations, **assumptions or simplifications** in your answer. **Brevity is acceptable**, but fuller explanations are better._

It's not just a link - it's a guide for Selenium + TestNG + Maven which contains an example of using ChromeDriver - exactly what the user needs.